# Racket Lisp - using 'read' with trying to parse the whole input string

Tags: parsing, scheme, lisp, racket

I use the function *read* in Racket for parsing arbitrary input strings.
For example,

```
 >(read (open-input-string "(1 (b 1))")) ; ==> returns '(1 (b 1))
```

In this example above the parentheses are matching - the problem is with input strings,
where the parentheses are unmatched/unbalanced, like

```
 > (read (open-input-string "(+ 1 1)(")) ; ==> returns '(+ 1 1)
```

In this case *read* ignores the last parentheses '(' in the input string -
I would like *read* to try parse the whole input string or when not possible,
because of unmatched parentheses, to throw an exception.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` procedure only reads a single datum from the input port; the extra parenth does not raise an error in your code because it is never reached. One solution is to write a procedure that reads from the input port until the end is reached, collecting the resulting forms in a list:

```
(define (read-from-string s)
  (let ((input (open-input-string s)))
    (let loop ((expr (read input))
               (result '()))
      (if (eof-object? expr)
          (reverse result)
          (loop (read input) (cons expr result))))))
```

If `read` can successfully parse all of the expressions, a list of those expressions will be returned; otherwise an error will be signaled.

Sample interactions:

```
scratch.rkt> (read-from-string "(1 (b 1))")
'((1 (b 1)))
scratch.rkt> (read-from-string "(+ 1 2)")
'((+ 1 2))
scratch.rkt> (read-from-string "(+ 1 2) (+ 3 4)")
'((+ 1 2) (+ 3 4))
scratch.rkt> (read-from-string "()")
'(())
scratch.rkt> (read-from-string "(+ 1 1))")
; string::8: read: unexpected `)`
scratch.rkt> (read-from-string "(+ 1 1)(")
; string::8: read: expected a `)` to close `(`
```